# Session issue in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, session, laravel-5.1

My app is built with Laravel 5.1. I have saved some data in session using the code, 
`session(['first_name' => Auth::user()->first_name])`. The value is set when user is logging in. It's working most of the times but sometimes the session value is being null. I don't know why automatically the session value is getting null. I am tired of solving this kind of weird problem. I need help.

Edited: Also the issue is more serious when user is not logged in with remember token active, the Auth::user() is also getting null for that user. And these situations are happening sometimes, not always. Don't know whether it is server problem or not.

Comment: If you have any routes group, please make sure you don't add the `web` middleware !!

Comment: I have not any route group and also I have not added the web middleware !!

Comment: Something about this implementation doesn't look right. The `Auth::user` info is normally stored in session, and if you're setting it all the time, of course it will throw an error (which may be silent) and of course be null when the user is not logged in..

Comment: As I don't want to use Auth::user all the times, so I put some frequently used data in session. And the issue arising when I am logged in. Also I am getting logged out when I am not logged in with remember token that means the Auth::user is also giving null value when remember token is not set.. That is more weird. I don't know is that a server problem or not.

Comment: Is this happening on your local machine or on some server?

Comment: This is happening on server, not on local machine. The full project is on server. Never tested on local machine.

Comment: You should switch your session driver to redis or memcache. If your server has a load balancer or it uses something else to distribute the requests, the session might get lost on the different machines.

Comment: Does file permission create any problem? In server the storage file permission is set to 775. I basically don't think that 775 file permission may create any problem but I am confused.